# Why is my scanf not taking in my choice and going through the loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, logic, scanf

Whenever I input the number 1, it keeps going through the print_menu(); function.

If choice was == to 1 I was expecting that the while loop will continue and go through the if statement, but it does not. Insted it keeps printing me the menu. Infact if I put any number it prints me the menu.

```
    while (run_game==TRUE) {
        print_menu();
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        choice = choice1;
        if (choice1 == 1) {
            while (hands<10);
            shuffle(card_deck);
            deal(card_deck, face, suit);
            print_hand(face, suit, p1_hand);
            printf("You have these cards in your hand:\n");
            p1_score = check_hand(p1_hand);
            p2_score = check_hand(p2_hand);
            printf("Player one has :%d points", p1_score);
            printf("Redraw card?\n 1.Yes, 2. No");
            scanf("%d", &ans);
            if (ans == 1) {
                while (ans > 3) {
                    print_hand(face, suit, p1_hand);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives, as well as the exact input required to reproduce the problem.

Comment: `while (hands<10);` is an infinite loop when `hands<10`

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to `scanf` to `choice1`?

```
 scanf("%d", &choice1);
```

If not, then the next line is overwriting `choice` and it's always going to be what `choice1` was at the start.

Comment: It worked but the while (hands<10); loop is not executing

Comment: This line: `while (hands<10);` creates a loop with no body (the `;` is the body). You have not shown us what `hands` is set to, so this is either an infinite loop (hands is always < 10) or it doesn't execute at all (hands >= 10).

Comment: This is probably not a good way to debug this program (asking questions on SO) -- you need to build it up more carefully (line by line) and get each line working the way you expect before moving on. If you know how to use a debugger, that would also help